# Dynamic multidimensional array on the heap

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, heap-memory

I want to create a function which can allocate a multidimensional array on the heap with only one call to malloc. (Pointer array) So a function call would look like this:

```
size_t dim[2]  = {2, 4};
int **_2darray = alloc_array(sizeof(int), dim, 2);
// ^ should be the "same" as:
int __2darray[2][4];
```

What I have so far is the SIZE computation of the whole block needed to hold the array and the pointers:

```
void *alloc_array(size_t element_size, size_t dimensions[static 1], size_t ndims)
{
    unsigned char *DATA = NULL;
    size_t SIZE         = 0;
    size_t multiplicators[ndims];

    // Calculate for each dimension the multiplier 
    // SIZE 3d array:  (N1 * sizeof(T **) + (N1 * N2 + sizeof(T *) + (N1 * N2 * n3 + sizeof(T))
    //                  ^- first mulitplier ^ second multiplier      ^ third multiplier

    for (size_t i = 0;  i < ndims; ++i) {
        multiplicators[i] = dimensions[i];

        for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            multiplicators[i] *= dimensions[j];
        }
    }

    SIZE = 0;
    for (size_t dimI = 0; dimI < ndims; ++dimI) {
        size_t mulval = multiplicators[dimI];

        // The elements are in the "last" dimension
        if (dimI+1 == ndims) {
            SIZE += element_size * mulval;
        } else {
            // All other elements are pointers to the specific element
            SIZE += sizeof(void *) * mulval;
        }
    }

    DATA = malloc(SIZE);
    return DATA;
}
```

So by now the SIZE calculation works. But now I'm stuck with setting the pointers to the right element. I know it's easy with dealing with static dimensions but I want this to be done with dynamic dimensions.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why not just malloc(sizeof(T) * dim1 * dim2) and be done with it?  Then index by computed offset like (row + col*nrows).

Comment: I want it to be dynamic, so that it works for any dimension. 2d,3d,4d..5d arrays.. I think you get the point.

Comment: No I don't.  Of course you should multiply sizeof(T) by all the dimensions.  That's a trivial "for" loop.    But your code is more complicated because you are dealing with pointers which I don't think you need to use.  If you malloc(sizeof(T) * dim1 * dim2 * dim3) then you index as (idx1 + idx2 * dim1 + idx3 * dim1 * dim2) or similar.

Comment: But then I need to cast the result or computate the index.

Comment: `int **_2darray` and `int __2darray[2][4];` are not compatible.

Comment: Quoting: `should be the "same" as:` I know the difference, but with `int **` I don't need to compute the index.

Comment: use `int (*_2darray)[4] = malloc(sizeof(int)*2*4);`. (malloc parts are the most important feature of the function)

Comment: Quoting: `I know it's easy with dealing with static dimensions`: then `4` never can be dynamic value. This is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: but  The number of  `*` is determined dynamically?

Comment: No again. If wrote I function like `get_2dvector()` then I would write `T **` because I know its a 2d vector. (This would work because `T **` can be casted to `void *`) With the other approach I would need a function which returns `int (*)[N]` which is definitely not possible. And casting would look ugly and needs two calls: `int N = get_2dvector_elems(); int (*array)[N] = get_2dvector();`

Comment: I feel like recursion may lead to a neater solution here.

Comment: My way anyway, `int **_2darray = alloc_array(sizeof(int), dim, 2);`,`int ***_3darray = alloc_array(sizeof(int), dim, 3);` Not going well also your way it's obvious. (you can not determine the number of `*` dynamically.) I think the method of @JohnZwinck to go well.

Comment: With this method I need to compute the index right? Thats ugly too!

Comment: @JohnZwinck provided you with the viable solution. To do what you want with a single `malloc` the information is held in a `1D` array of size `size` but can be accessed as a `2D` vector array in any combination of `array[row][col]` where `size = row * col`. This is simply done by setting the `stride` or `offset` defining the number elements in each vector. Any `array[x][y]` value is `array[(x*stride)+y]`. This allows any `36` element `1D` array to be handled as either a `1x36`, `2x18`, `4x9` or `6x6`. There just are not that many different ways to do this constrained to a single `malloc`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin but then I need to compute the index, that is not what I want.

Comment: We are talking about different sides of the same coin. In attempting to do what you want to do, compute the `index` for any number of dimensions, instead of a simple `stride` for the `2D` case, you want a similar calculation for the `xD` case. This just adds additional `offsets` and `multipliers` to `stride`. The approach is the same as the `2D` case, only the number and complexity of the `multiple-strides` required changes. That appears to be the reason @OliverCharlesworth suggested a recursive approach. Basically, you are left needing a `linear-algebra` proof describing the logic.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OK now I get it, but I have no Idea how to implement this.

Comment: When I started thinking through a generic `nDimension` space model, my head exploded... Each new dimension adds several additional layers of offset. Coding functions for `2D` is doable, but tedious. Implementing a generic set would be a doctoral thesis.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The trick is to not worry about the entire n-dimensional model, but just the inductive definition.  The 1D version is simply linear storage of elements.  The nD version is a set of pointers plus a set of (n-1)D versions.  Code to generate this recursively is almost trivial.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth could you please give an example?

Comment: @d3l: Try drawing a diagram that corresponds to the description I just gave.  Then implement the code for it!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth of course your correct, but the devil always comes in the declaration details, in forming the solution flexible enough to actually handle `n-Dimensions`. (well `n-1` as you point out) I agree regarding a recursive implementation being the solution (probably the only realistic coding solution). Intellectually the **get element index/value** doesn't seem nearly as bad as thinking through **row, col, d-next** `vector` mappings. I guess neither are impossible, but both will remain intellectual exercises for the foreseeable future. I don't have that much Aspirin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void fill_array_pointers (void** pointers, char* elements, 
                  size_t element_size, size_t total_elements_size, 
                  size_t dimensions[], size_t ndims)
{
    if (ndims == 2)
    {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; ++i)
        {
            pointers[i] = elements + i * element_size * dimensions[1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        size_t i;
        size_t block_size = total_elements_size / dimensions[0];
        for (i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; ++i)
        {
            pointers[i] = pointers + dimensions[0] + i * dimensions[1];
            fill_array_pointers (pointers + dimensions[0] 
                                          + i * dimensions[1], 
                                  elements + block_size * i, 
                                  element_size, block_size, 
                                  dimensions+1, ndims-1);
        }
    }
}

void* alloc_array (size_t element_size, size_t dimensions[], 
                    size_t ndims)
{
    size_t total_elements_size = element_size;
    int i;

    // total size of elements

    for (i = 0; i < ndims; ++i)
        total_elements_size *= dimensions[i];

    // total size of pointers

    size_t total_pointers_size = 0;
    int mulval = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < ndims-1; ++i)
    {
        total_pointers_size += dimensions[i] * sizeof(void*) * mulval;
        mulval *= dimensions[i];
    }

    size_t total_size = total_pointers_size;
    size_t oddball = total_pointers_size % element_size; 
                // really needs to be alignof but we don't have it
    if (oddball) total_size += (element_size - oddball);
    total_size += total_elements_size;

    void* block = malloc (total_size);
    void** pointers = block;
    char* elements = (char*)block + total_size - total_elements_size;

    fill_array_pointers (pointers, elements, element_size,
                         total_elements_size, dimensions, ndims);
    return block;
}
```

Test drive:

```
int main ()
{
    size_t dims[] = { 2, 3, 4 };
    int*** arr = alloc_array(sizeof(int), dims, 3);


    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < dims[0]; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < dims[1]; ++j)
            for (k = 0; k < dims[2]; ++k)
            {
                arr[i][j][k] = i*100+j*10+k;
            }

    for (i = 0; i < dims[0]*dims[1]*dims[2]; ++i)
    {
        printf ("%03d ", (&arr[0][0][0])[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    free (arr);
}
```

This will not work for multidimensional `char` arrays on systems where `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(char**)`; such systems exist but are rare. Multidimensional `char` arrays are pointless anyway.

The test runs cleanly under `valgrind`.

This is more an intellectual exercise than anything else. If you need maximum performance, don't use arrays of pointers, use a flat array and ugly but efficient explicit index calculations. If you need clear and concise code, you are probably better off allocating each level separately.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works as expected! But why should a multidimensional char array be pointless?

Comment: `char` is the unit of storage and the unit of exchange between the computer and the outside world, and is not much good for anything else. Both these things are mostly one-dimensional. One could also use `char` as a generic small integer, but on these weird systems it would probably be rather inefficient.